# rosjava - Subscriber java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:37172 - Connection refused

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to start a ros Subscriber an android device. My sourcecode look like:

```
String hostLocal = InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostAddress();
String hostMaster = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHostValue)).getText().toString();
Integer port = Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPortValue)).getText().toString());
URI uri = URI.create("http://" + hostMaster + ":" + port);              
            
NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(hostLocal, uri);          
nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(uri);
nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("nodeName");  
nodeRunner.run(new Listener(), nodeConfiguration);
```

If i start the ros-master local on my android device - it works fine. But if the
master is running an my PC (for example: hostMaster = "192.168.178.29"), i get an error:

```
E/UpdatePublisherRunnable(10630): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:37172 - Connection refused
```

by trying to debug your sourcecode and I have seen in  'MasterClien.java' file a following  function:

```
return Response.fromListChecked(node.registerSubscriber(slave.getName().toString(), subscriber
        .getTopicName().toString(), subscriber.getTopicMessageType(), slave.getUri()
        .toString()), new UriListResultFactory());
```

Befor I had called a funciton, I had  follwing screen:

[image description http://gonzik.de:81/vor2.png](http://gonzik.de:81/vor2.png)

But after calling of function I have seen:

[image description http://gonzik.de:81/nach2.png](http://gonzik.de:81/nach2.png)

You can see, that after calling a funciton it is the uri of client not the same. Is this issue known or not. What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12496/rosjava---subscriber-java.net.connectexception:-localhost/127.0.0.1:37172---connection-refused/) by [eugen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1589/eugen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like you have not set [ROS_IP](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME) on your host PC.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0